# Почему input внизу и как это исправить?

Tags: html, css

```css
.bar {
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
}

input {
  border: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 20px;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 40px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.bar:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 1px #dcdcdc;
}

svg {
  position: relative;
  padding: -100px -100px;
  margin: 12px
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bar">
    <svg focusable="false">
            <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27A6.471 6.471 0 0 0 16 9.5 6.5 6.5 0 1 0 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
        </svg>
    <input type="text" style="border:none;">
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приветствуем Вас на Stackoverflow!  Не забудьте пожалуйста, поблагодарить автора ответа (отметьте галочку и треугольник рядом с цифрой ответа)

Answer (score 3):

У Вас `<svg>` имеет высоту в 150px и находиться в одном потоке с `<input>`. Именно `<svg>` и отталкивает `<input>` вниз. Нужно `<svg>` задать `position: absolute;`.

```css
.bar {
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  border: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 20px;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 40px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.bar:hover { box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 1px #dcdcdc; }

svg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: -100px -100px;
  margin: 12px
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bar">
    <svg focusable="false">
            <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27A6.471 6.471 0 0 0 16 9.5 6.5 6.5 0 1 0 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
        </svg>
    <input type="text" style="border:none;">
  </div>
</body>
```